# How to get the earliest time each day and the last?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How do I get the first time in and the last time of each day out?

Is it possible to use an if condition or macros?

```
A
2018-08-17 12:03:29
2018-08-17 09:53:28
2018-08-16 18:49:31
2018-08-16 18:39:57
2018-08-16 18:24:18
2018-08-16 16:57:21
2018-08-16 16:37:35
2018-08-16 12:41:24
2018-08-16 09:14:27
2018-08-16 09:05:39
2018-08-15 21:18:56
2018-08-15 19:13:48
2018-08-15 14:03:07
2018-08-15 13:51:44
2018-08-15 13:33:23
2018-08-15 13:28:48
2018-08-15 09:13:26
2018-08-14 19:48:04
2018-08-14 19:27:36
2018-08-14 19:26:47
2018-08-14 16:37:59
2018-08-14 14:31:30
2018-08-14 11:03:38
2018-08-14 08:26:19
```

Comment: You can use a pivot table to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have the newer MINIFS/MAXIFS functions then you require pseudo-MINIFS/MAXIFS functions constructed from combining older functions.

```
'MINIFS
=MIN(INDEX(A$1:A$24+(A$1:A$24<E2)*1E+99, , ))
'MAXIFS
=MAX(INDEX(A$1:A$24+(A$1:A$24>=E2+1)*-1E+99, , ))
```

[image]

Comment: just adding to Jeeped's answer.  The green date values in column E can be formulas as well.  First entry could be `=INT(MIN(A:A))` or `=INT(MIN($A$1:$A$24)).  Subsequent rows simply point to the cell above and add 1  (`=E2+1).  just format the cell as a date.